# Python library for recording PC audio only

Tags: windows, library, python, audio, audio-recording

I just wanted to record my Python program's audio output only. So, are there any libraries for this purpose?

> PS: Not microphone only the PC audio.

Edited

I'm looking for something that has some function to record the PC audio only. Example : `recordPcAudio(True)`. Something like that would be ok.

Comment: Have you tried to search for something? Can you update your question? I found several topics on this literally after few seconds of googling...

Answer (score 2):

There is a [PyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) project, that can record system's sounds (and many more).
If you go through documentation, you can find that opening a stream has several parameters (described [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#pyaudio.Stream.__init__)). In your case, you should set:

- input: False (because not listening any input devices)
- output: True (this will enable system sound recording)
- output_device_index: ID (to record only on specific sound device or leave it to collect all sounds)